# npx create-react-app

Tags: paquetes-npm

[image: []

Hola tengo problemas al intentar aplicar npx create-react-app por favor necesito soluciones al error Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'test'

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te esta diciendo que no tenes permisos para crear esa carpeta ahi.. tenes permisos?

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: parece que no tienes permisos para crear archivos en el directorio especificado, intenta abrir la terminal ejecutando como administrador, puedes intentar cambiar el directorio del proyecto o cambiar los permisos del directorio manualmente

Comment: Hola DarioFerrer bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias. 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.